# React native populating table data from json

Tags: react-native

I have a table to display some data;

```
  state = {
    tableHead: ['Pos', '', 'P', 'W', 'D', 'L', 'GD', 'PTS'],
    tableData: [
      ['  1', 'AAAA', '0', '0', '0', '0', ' 0', '  0'],
      ['  2', 'XXXX', '0', '0', '0', '0', ' 0', '  0'],
      ['  3', 'BBBB', '0', '0', '0', '0', ' 0', '  0'],
      ['  4', 'CCCC', '0', '0', '0', '0', ' 0', '  0'],
      ['  5', 'DDDD', '0', '0', '0', '0', ' 0', '  0'],
      ['  6', 'QQWE', '0', '0', '0', '0', ' 0', '  0']
    ]
  }
```

The above is hardcoded but I want to pull it from a JSON file. I can fetch a JSON file, but the formatting of how to write out the table data is my challenge;

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/league1stteam.json')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
          setData(json)
          data.forEach(obj => {
            Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
                alert((`${key} ${value}`))
                //['  1', 'NEW RECORD', '0', '0', '0', '0', ' 0', '  0']
            });
        });
        })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  }, []);
```

What is the right approach to looping and pre-populating the data table list with the JSON record values?

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, In the past I used [react-native-data-table](https://github.com/sussol/react-native-data-table). It's the easiest way I found to make a data table from JSON in react-native.

Basically, to render a row you can use `renderRow` function like this:

```
renderRow(record) {
  <Row>
    <Cell>record.code</Cell>
    <Cell>record.name</Cell>
    <EditableCell
      value={record.quantity}
    />
  </Row>
}
```